# Как переписать js

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтоб можно было добавлять сколько угодно элементов select и они все одинаково работали?

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");

const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
  optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList.forEach(o => {
  o.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #f7f6ff;
}

h2 {
  margin: 16px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 32px;
}

.select-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
}

.selected {
  background: #2f3640;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("img/arrow-down.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.select-box .options-container.active {
  max-height: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.select-box .options-container.active+.selected::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -6px;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background: #0d141f;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #525861;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .option,
.selected {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option:hover {
  background: #414b57;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option .radio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Video Category</h2>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
          <label for="automobiles">Automobiles</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
          <label for="film">Film & Animation
              <img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyMCAxNiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTcgMTZMMiAxMkw3IDhWMTFIMjBWMTNIN1YxNlpNMTMgOFY1SDBWM0gxM1YwTDE4IDRMMTMgOFoiIGZpbGw9IiNEQ0RDREMiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
          <label for="science">Science & Technology</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
          <label for="art">Art</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
          <label for="music">Music</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
          <label for="travel">Travel & Events</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sports" name="category" />
          <label for="sports">Sports</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
          <label for="news">News & Politics</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="tutorials" name="category" />
          <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="selected">
        Select Video Category
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
          <label for="automobiles">Automobiles</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
          <label for="film">Film & Animation
              <img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyMCAxNiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTcgMTZMMiAxMkw3IDhWMTFIMjBWMTNIN1YxNlpNMTMgOFY1SDBWM0gxM1YwTDE4IDRMMTMgOFoiIGZpbGw9IiNEQ0RDREMiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
          <label for="science">Science & Technology</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
          <label for="art">Art</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
          <label for="music">Music</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
          <label for="travel">Travel & Events</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sports" name="category" />
          <label for="sports">Sports</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
          <label for="news">News & Politics</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="tutorials" name="category" />
          <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="selected">
        Select Video Category
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать чтоб можно было добавлять сколько угодно элементов select и они все одинаково работали?

Предложу такой вариант...

Его суть в делегировании событий. На родителя вешается один обработчик, который анализирует на чем именно кликнули и выполняет нужные действия.

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener('click', e => {
  const ob = e.target.closest('.select-box');
  if (!ob) return
  const optionsContainer = ob.querySelector('.options-container');
  let selected = e.target.closest(".selected");
  if (selected) {
    optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
    return
  } 
  const o = e.target.closest(".option");
  if (!o) return
  selected = ob.querySelector(".selected");
  selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
  optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #f7f6ff;
}

h2 {
  margin: 16px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 32px;
}

.select-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.select-box .options-container {
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
}

.selected {
  background: #2f3640;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  position: relative;
  order: 0;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("img/arrow-down.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.select-box .options-container.active {
  max-height: 240px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.select-box .options-container.active+.selected::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  top: -6px;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background: #0d141f;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #525861;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.select-box .option,
.selected {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option:hover {
  background: #414b57;
}

.select-box label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box .option .radio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Video Category</h2>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
          <label for="automobiles">Automobiles</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
          <label for="film">Film & Animation
              <img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyMCAxNiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTcgMTZMMiAxMkw3IDhWMTFIMjBWMTNIN1YxNlpNMTMgOFY1SDBWM0gxM1YwTDE4IDRMMTMgOFoiIGZpbGw9IiNEQ0RDREMiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
          <label for="science">Science & Technology</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
          <label for="art">Art</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
          <label for="music">Music</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
          <label for="travel">Travel & Events</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sports" name="category" />
          <label for="sports">Sports</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
          <label for="news">News & Politics</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="tutorials" name="category" />
          <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="selected">
        Select Video Category
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select-box">
      <div class="options-container">
        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="automobiles" name="category" />
          <label for="automobiles">Automobiles</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
          <label for="film">Film & Animation
              <img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyMCAxNiIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdGggZD0iTTcgMTZMMiAxMkw3IDhWMTFIMjBWMTNIN1YxNlpNMTMgOFY1SDBWM0gxM1YwTDE4IDRMMTMgOFoiIGZpbGw9IiNEQ0RDREMiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
          <label for="science">Science & Technology</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
          <label for="art">Art</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
          <label for="music">Music</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
          <label for="travel">Travel & Events</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sports" name="category" />
          <label for="sports">Sports</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
          <label for="news">News & Politics</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input type="radio" class="radio" id="tutorials" name="category" />
          <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="selected">
        Select Video Category
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
for (let index = 0; index < selected.length; index++) {
 let tab = selected[index];
 tab.addEventListener("click", e => {
  var selectedTarget = e.target;
  selectedTarget.parentNode.classList.toggle('active') && selectedTarget.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
 });
}`

Comment: я первую часть вот так сделал а дальше пока не придумал))

Comment: в вашем варианте при выборе меняется значение у обоих

Comment: @СлаваГрачев, в моем примере меняется только тот, в котором и выбрали опцию.

Comment: Да сейчас норм... сорри

Comment: @СлаваГрачев, так я и не правил ничего...

Comment: Да наверное из-за того что они в примере близко друг к другу на жал как-то не так... по коду все норм